# select element with at least 1000 hidden options can result in one-line dropdowns

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am using a `select` element with over 1000 `option` elements in Chrome. To make the `select` easier to use I allow the user to hide `option` elements that do not match an input string. The number of `option` elements is always well below Chrome's [10000 maximum](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/core/html/HTMLSelectElement.cpp#77). However, I noticed a condition where the dropdown list becomes one item high with a scrollbar. Normally the dropdown accomodates 20 items before a scrollbar appears.

I made a minimal example that displays two identical `select` elements with over 1000 `option` elements each. The ONLY difference is which `option` is selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form style='position:absolute;right:50%;margin:1%'><select id='dropdown1'></select></form>
        <form style='position:absolute;left:50%;margin:1%'><select id='dropdown2'></select></form>

        <script>
            const dropdown1 = document.querySelector('#dropdown1');
            const dropdown2 = document.querySelector('#dropdown2');
            const firstItem = 1000; 
            const lastItem = firstItem + 10;

            for (let i = 0; i <= lastItem; i++) {
                const option1 = document.createElement('option');
                const option2 = document.createElement('option');
                option1.text = option2.text = i;
                option1.hidden = option2.hidden = i < firstItem;
                dropdown1.appendChild(option1);
                dropdown2.appendChild(option2);
            }

            dropdown1.selectedIndex = firstItem;
            dropdown2.selectedIndex = lastItem;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CODEPEN is [here](https://codepen.io/jgeduldig/pen/XWdExMz). And, here is the result:

[image]

UPDATE: On MacOS there is no issue with google Chrome. The issue occurs on Windows.

Comment: So, what is your question? This seems more like an bug report for Google Chrome and should be posted as such

Comment: Per your suggestion, a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1128406) was submitted

Comment: Thank you :) I love that